# Different way of representing the linked images in Meta sites

Tags: feature-request, design, hyperlinks, images

I just recently noticed that all the images in Meta Sites, (other than this) have a crazy grey colour theme, which is fine, and for links we use a `border-bottom: dashed`, which is also okay for links. The crazy part about this post is, it gets applied for the images as well like a dotted underline. Do we really need it?

[image: preview]

Can we please remove this? Looks not okay for me.

**Update**

To differentiate the linked image vs. normal image, (well, there's none on this meta site), I propose something like this:

[image]

The above image is the full image, so part, showing the right way of my proposal:

[image]

Comment: But it indicates to me that the image is clickable. Why would a linked image behave differently than a regular link?

Comment: @animuson Ah! But we can give something better right? Like border on all the sides?

Comment: @animuson Have a look at the proposal I shared. `:)`